# 2 Halves of a Triangle CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a CSS animation in which two halves of a triangle split apart in go in opposite directions.

In order to achieve this I need to create a triangle, first. But more importantly the triangle needs to be in 2 halves which you can separately animate. I have searched far and wide on the web and found nothing! I cant believe no one has tried before. Hopefully you CSS wizards can help make this possible. (if you want you can add the animation too! its simple so I don't mind if you don't, thanks.)

Comment: would you consider using SVG instead on HTML?

Comment: yeah that could work but i dont have any svg's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover over the triangle to see the animation (splitting in halves):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 100px;
}
.triangle-4 {
  left:0;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: solid 30px rgb(200,30,50);
  border-left: solid 30px transparent; /**/
  border-right: solid 30px transparent;
  border-top: solid 30px transparent;
}
section:hover > .triangle-5 {
  left: 50px;
}
section:hover > .triangle-4 {
  left: -50px;
}
.triangle-5 {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: solid 30px transparent;
  border-left: solid 30px black;
  border-right: solid 30px transparent;
  border-top: solid 30px transparent;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="triangle triangle-4"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle-5"></div>
</section>
```

[References: Triangles](https://codepen.io/callmenick/pen/YzGEgE?editors=1100)

---

**Isosceles Triangle**:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
.triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.triangle-4 {
  left:30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: solid 200px red;
  border-left: solid 0px transparent;
  border-right: solid 60px transparent;
  border-top: solid 30px transparent;
}
section:hover > .triangle-5 {
  left: -80px;
}
section:hover > .triangle-4 {
  left: 80px;
}
.triangle-5 {
  left:-30px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: solid 200px red;
  border-right: solid 0px transparent;
  border-left: solid 60px transparent;
  border-top: solid 30px transparent;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="triangle triangle-4"></div>
  <div class="triangle triangle-5"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: is there a way to make is a isosceles triangle?

Comment: ok cool, thank you. Also sorry for so many requests but is it possible to make it shorter like just taller than a equilateral but not a equilateral, or if you can include a equilateral that would be nice Thank You! Marked you as answer!!

Comment: also if you could include how i could tune it to my liking that would be appreciated! So i dont have to keep commenting

Comment: It's up to you to tweak the CSS values of the width, height and border-width for these examples and come up with different triangle setups. Play around and experiment with these values to get the setup that you want.